# Navigate to another view if video play was initiated

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let say I have a ViewController VC1 and another VC2. VC1 contains a webView with a textView to enter URL and webView loads that URL.

If user enters a website URL it should load in the same view and if user enters a URL which contains play video option, most likely Youtube. Here is the thing; if user taps Play button it should navigate to VC2 and play the video there and when video finishes it goes back to VC1 or if user manually taps Done button to end the video.

How can I do so ?